# Waiting for contract to receive an ERC721 token

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, erc-721, interfaces

I'm trying to create a smart contract for raffling a NFT between users. Whenever an user tries create a raffle they need to specify the `tokenContract` which is the contract address of the NFT, and the `tokenId` which will be the corresponding id. I'm using a simple minting contract to simulate sending a token to the contract. However, when sending the raffle contract the minted token, and having `onERC721Received` set up, the `State` doesn't get changed to `1`.

According to [etherscan](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x213947395eabd7240b2e8f0fcbff2d96a133fd84#tokentxnsErc721) the raffle contract did successfully receive the ERC721 token.

Relevant part of raffle contract:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";

...

contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBase, IERC721Receiver {

    enum State {
        Pending,
        Active,
        Calculating,
        Finished
    }

    State public state;

    ...
    ...

    function onERC721Received(address, address, uint256, bytes calldata) external override returns (bytes4) {
        state = State.Active;
        
        return IERC721Receiver.onERC721Received.selector;
    }
```

Minting contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
 
contract TestToken is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
     using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721("TestToken", "TST") {}
 
    function mintNFT(address recipient)
        public onlyOwner
        returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();
 
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(recipient, newItemId);
 
        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you internalize the transfer process and use the standard ERC721 library?

```
function transferNFT(address _nft, uint256 _tokenId) public {
    // Check if sender approved contract to use _tokenId
    require(ERC721(_nft).getApproved(_tokenId) == address(this) ||
        isApprovedForAll(tx.origin, address(this)) == true,
        "Not approved to transfer NFT");
    // Check if sender is the owner of _tokenId
    require(ERC721(_nft).ownerOf(_tokenId) == tx.origin, "Not owner of token");

    // Process transaction
    ERC721(_nft).transferFrom(tx.origin, address(this), _tokenId);

    // Check that transaction was successful
    require(ERC721(_nft).ownerOf(_tokenId) == address(this), "Transfer failed");
}
```

You can utilize the standard ERC721 ownerOf function to verify that the transfer completed after calling the transfer function.